# Figuring out ATX Power Supply max output

Tags: current, 12v, atx

I have a Delta DPS-400AB-17B power supply, and I am planning to change over some of the connectors to different ones. I want to make sure I don't overload any of the 12v 18awg wires, so I am figuring out how to disperse the load evenly across the available 12v wires (keeping rails in mind). The power supply has 12 12v terminating wires (2x for 24 Pin, 4x for one EPS 12v connector, 4x for another EPS 12v connector, and 2x for 2 SATA), however many of these 12v wires "share" a connection to the PSU's PCB, as such:

[image]

My initial thought was that this would possibly be a thicker wire, but it is 18awg just like the others. Should I be concerned about this small (roughly 2") section of wire heating up too much because it is carrying twice as much current as any of the other single 12v wires, or does the fact that it is only a very small run change the wire's ampacity at all?

Comment: Can you look up AWG R/ft?

Answer (score 1):

There are two 12V outputs on that supply, each rated at 21A.

The run is probably not short enough to change the ampacity of the wire much, however it will reduce the voltage drop (which is often the limiting factor). 21A may or may not be too much current for AWG 18 depending on the environment and the temperature rating of the insulation.